$\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$, then $I,A,\cdots, A^{r+1}$ is linearly dependent

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$, then $I,A,\cdots, A^{r+1}$ is linearly dependent.

I know just if the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $k$, then $I, A, \cdots, A^{k-1}$ is linearly independent, and $I, A, \cdots, A^k$ is linearly dependent.
So we deduce that $r+1\geq k$; how do we relate the rank and the minimal polynomial? Something I lose?

Can you give us the dimension of $A$?

@Surb your example are all linearly dependent, no contradiction.

Try bringing your matrix into a block upper (or lower depending on your mood) triangular form where one of the diagonal blocks is a $(n-r) \times (n-r)$ 0-matrix ($n$ being the dimension of the underlying space).

Try to use Cayley-Hamilton theorem that states that every square matrix over a commutative ring (such as the real or complex numbers or the integers) satisfies its own characteristic equation.

@SebastianSchoennenbeck This may impossible, for exmaple surb gives. since you need diagonal blocks.

@xldd Why would that be impossible? Surb's example is already in this form.

You can do a bit better: without using $I$, those positive powers of $A$ are already linearly dependent. Let $V$ be the image (column space) of $A$, then by definition of the rank one has $\dim(V)=r$, and so the characteristic polynomial$~\chi$ of the restriction$~A'$ of multiplication by $A$ to $V$ has
$\deg\chi=r$. Then by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $\chi[A']=0$, which means that $\chi[A]$ vanishes on $V$. But then $(\chi X)[A]=\chi[A]\cdot{A}$ vanishes everywhere, so it is $0$. Then we can take the coefficients of this product polynomial $\chi X$ as those of a linear combination of the positive powers of$~A$, from $A^1$ up to $A^{r+1}$, and this (non trivial) linear combination is $0$.
